# PHP use in_array to check array against another array

Tags: php

I am trying to check if any values out or array $a1 are present in array $a2 in PHP...

```
$a1 = array(
    "a"=>"red",
    "b"=>"green",
    "c"=>"blue",
    "d"=>"yellow"
);

$a2 = array(
    "b"=>"green",
    "c"=>"blue",
);
```

I have tried to compare using `in_array` like this...

```
if (in_array($a1, $a2)) {
  echo "Match found";
}
```

But this is not working, I think this is because in_array does not support checking an array against an array.  What is the correct method?

Comment: did u tried `array_diff()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_intersect_assoc`

```
$res =array_intersect_assoc($a1, $a2);
```

[Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/iAXW9)